# How to handle 'intermediate' JSON rest service parameters in Spring?

Tags: json, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Spring development and am currently looking for best practices for creating objects based on JSON data passed to a rest service, which are then to be stored using JPA.

As an example, let's assume a simplified file upload service where clients can post the following JSON object to:

```
{"filename":"myfile.pdf", "data":someByteArray, "extension":"pdf"}
```

On the server, I don't want to store the file's raw data in the database, but upload it to some cloud storage and just store a link to it. So once the "data" parameter content is stored and the link is received, it is obsolete.

The options I've come up with is:

a) define one 'union' class to deserialize the request body that comprises all fields ("filename", "link", "extension" AND "data"), marking 'intermediate' data as @Transient, so it won't be stored in the database,

b) define two classes: one solely for deserializing the request body ("filename", "data", "extension") which is then used to construct the desired entity class ("filename", "link", "extension") that is to be stored,

c) define a custom JsonDeserializer that parses the request body and constructs the entity class ("filename", "link", "extension").

While all of the approaches will probably work, in a more complex scenario, option a) will clutter the entity's class with members that are only required for deserializing once, while option b) and c) may result in a lot of additional classes.

Is there any best practice for this? Btw, thanks for reading this far :)

Comment: I'd go with b. I don't see why you would use a single class to represent a persistent row of your database table, and a data exchange structure. They're not the same thing, don't belong to the same application layer, and don't contain the same information. In my experience, mixing 2 responsibilities in a single class brings more problems than it solves. And the data exchange class should be very simple to implement.

Comment: putting it that way, b really does make sense - thank you very much.